# Query string of the URL getting removed in mobile for HTML's <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

This is very strange issue - I have a very simple HTML anchor tag as below (ofcourse this not all the code, there is much more). It works great for laptop browsers but in Samsung note browser when I click this (exact URL is not for Google's but my application's URL) then query string part automatically gets removed/truncated and I am only left with URL without query string opened in a new window.

```
<a id="gog" href="http://localhost/WebContent/index.jsp?abc=ABC" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Google</a>
```

Originally, the href value I was building dynamically in the `href` attribute itself, I though mobile doesn't allow that so I computed the full URL separately and then used that variable in `href` but it didn't help.

Then I thought may be `rel="noreferrer"` is causing issue but to no avail.

This happens only in mobile device - Samsung and Chrome browser, laptop Chrome is fine.

Anybody has ever faced this issue or any idea on how to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is malformed; you need a `/` between the host portion and the path / querystring.

Also, to make the URL actually work, you should change that to `/search`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am sure my URL is not malformed, I didn't want to put the exact URL, now replaced it placeholder and provided actual thing. What's your view now?

Comment: Mobile devices won't have a server on `localhost` to connect to.

Comment: You are not getting my point, I hv already said this is a placeholder URL, so can assume that instead of `localhost` it is some valid DNS name ..

Comment: Without seeing the _actual_ URL, I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Let say it is `http://hagrawal.slaks/WebContent/index.jsp?abc=ABC` .. I think it have got the issue, issue looks to be that I originally have  application 1 in browser window 1 which opens another application 2 in window 2 using `window.open(myURL,'_blank')`, now from the window 2 I am trying to open a window 3 which is nothing but the application 1 but this time have some additional query string in URL .. Looks like issue is with some parent-child relationship in windows .. Any idea on resolution ??

Comment: Any idea ?? I have tried `target` attribute but it will not help much because I want a new window ..